# Monoprice Maker Ultimate Extrudes Too Much Filament At Start

Tags: g-code, extrusion, simplify3d, wanhao, monoprice-maker-ultimate

Today I received my Monoprice Maker Ultimate 3D Printer. It is a rebranded Wanhao Duplicator 6 for reference. I am using the default settings for a Wanhao Duplicator 6 in Simplify3D.

Here is the Start G-Code that Simplify3D has setup for me via the Configuration Assistant:

```
G28 ; home all axes
G92 E0 ; zero the extruded length
G1 Z10 ; lower
G1 E20 F200 ; purge nozzle quickly
G1 E10 F60 ; purge nozzle slowly
G92 E0 ; zero the extruded length again
G1 E-1.5 F400 ; retract
G1 X170 Z0 F9000 ; pull away filament
G1 X180 F9000 ; wipe
G1 Y20 F9000 ; wipe
G1 E0 ; feed filament back
```

The problem is that right before a print, the extruder squeezes out a bunch of filament making a nice little spiral tower. It is a waste of filament. I suspect it is all the purging in the Start Code that is doing it, but I don't know what I should change because I don't know what is necessary, so I am coming here to ask the question before I start experimenting. Has anyone had this problem? Does anyone know the solution?

Update: I tried printing one of the models that came on the SD card with the printer (I think it was created with Cura) and the Start G-code is different.

```
G21        ;metric values
G90        ;absolute positioning
M82        ;set extruder to absolute mode
M107       ;start with the fan off
G28 X0 Y0  ;move X/Y to min endstops
G28 Z0     ;move Z to min endstops
G1 Z15.0 F4800 ;move the platform down 15mm
G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length
G1 F200 E3              ;extrude 3mm of feed stock
G92 E0                  ;zero the extruded length again
G1 F4800
;Put printing message on LCD screen
M117 Printing...
```

It also uses absolute positioning. It got going without purging a bunch of unnecessary filament on that print. Now I am not sure how to combine these two to get the good working starting G-code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the Simplify3D start script to this will change the nozzle purge to the same length as what was on your SD card.

```
    G28 ; home all axes
    G92 E0 ; zero the extruded length
    G1 Z10 ; lower
    G1 E20 F200 ; purge nozzle quickly<---------Change E20 to E3, E is the extrusion length
    G1 E10 F60 ; purge nozzle slowly <----------Remove this line
    G92 E0 ; zero the extruded length again
    G1 E-1.5 F400 ; retract
    G1 X170 Z0 F9000 ; pull away filament
    G1 X180 F9000 ; wipe
    G1 Y20 F9000 ; wipe
    G1 E0 ; feed filament back
```

The rest of it is just moves to try to clean the nozzle.